# how to get unique strings from a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a csv file with four columns: voter id, county, and candidate

I have read the file in as a dictionary and have checked that my keys are the column headers. I have a task of getting all the unique names of the candidates (there are 4)

My code in its current form is returning, what I believe to be the unique letters in their names, instead of the entire name.

The expected output should be (O'Toole, Jackson, Kendall, Stewart)
What I am getting is {'l','a','o','T;,''','r','y','K'}

```py
candidate_names = []
    for row in csvreader:
        for x in row['Candidate'] #candidate is the key name
        candidate_names.append(x)

unique_names = set(candidate_names)
print(unique_names)
```

Comment: Would you like to share what was the input, output and expected results.

Comment: `row["Candidate"]` will be a string.  Iterating over a string will get its characters one by one.  Try removing `for x in row["Candidate"]:` and instead just do `candidate_names.append(row["Candidate"])`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `for x in row['Candidate']`. You are looping through the letters in the name and adding that. If you add that directly into the list, it will work fine!

Like this:

```py
candidate_names = []
    for row in csvreader:
        candidate_names.append(row['Candidate'])
unique_names = set(candidate_names)
print(unique_names)
```